# How to pass a request header to fastify plugin options at register

Tags: graphql, fastify

I can access the request header in a get or post call

```
fastify.get('/route1',(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(req.headers.Authorization)
  ...
}
```

I am looking for a way to pass it to a plugin register call, specifically [fastify-graphql](https://github.com/sirsavary/fastify-graphql/issues/11)

```
const { graphqlFastify } = require("fastify-graphql");
fastify.register(graphqlFastify,
         {
            prefix: "/graphql",
            graphql: {
                schema: schema,
                rootValue: resolvers,
                context:{auth:req.headers.Authorization}    <-----
            }
        },
        err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
        }
 );
```

Is there a way to write a wrapper or any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that.

If read the code you will find that:

- [fastify-graphql](https://github.com/sirsavary/fastify-graphql/blob/49015f9c42a6d606111fdbadb6690a7315a4dadf/src/GraphQLPlugin.ts#L13) is calling `runHttpQuery`
- [runHttpQuery](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/bd2504e04b632355ffc9b8d5846a328234b799e4/packages/apollo-server-core/src/runHttpQuery.ts#L135) is calling `context` without passing the request

So I think that you should check the auth-client with a standard JWT and then use another token server-side.

The final solution could be to check Apollo 2.0 and open the issue on fastify-graphql.

Here a little snippet that explain the idea:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
const { graphiqlFastify, graphqlFastify } = require('fastify-graphql');


const typeDefs = `
type Query {
    demo: String,
    hello: String
}
`
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    demo: (parent, args, context) => {
      console.log({ args, context });
      return 'demo'
    },
    hello: () => 'world'
  }
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })

fastify.register(graphqlFastify, {
  prefix: '/gr',
  graphql: {
    schema,
    context: function () {
      return { serverAuth: 'TOKEN' }
    },
  },
});

fastify.listen(3000)

// curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/gr' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query": "{ demo }"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who need to access request headers in graphql context, try 
[graphql-fastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-fastify)

#### Usage

```
Create /graphql endpoint like following

const graphqlFastify = require("graphql-fastify");

fastify.register(graphqlFastify, {
    prefix: "/graphql",
    graphQLOptions
});
```

#### graphQLOptions

graphQLOptions can be provided as an object or a function that returns graphql options

```
graphQLOptions: {
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: resolver
    contextValue?: context
}
```

If it is a function, you have access to http request and response. This allows you to do authentication and pass authentication scopes to graphql context. See the following pseudo-code

```
const graphQLOptions = function (request,reply) {
    const auth = decodeBearerToken(request.headers.Authorization);
    // auth may contain userId, scope permissions

    return  {
         schema: schema,
         rootValue: resolver,
         contextValue: {auth}
     }
});
```

This way, context.auth is accessible to resolver functions allowing you to check user's scope/permissions before proceeding.